# Grep aliases and run them

Tags: bash, grep, alias

Hi I want grep all aliases and run their "body"

```
alias | grep NAME
```

it's return:

```
alias NAME123='ping google123.com'
alias NAME321='ping google321.com'
...
```

I want to run: 
ping google123.com
ping google321.com
but not 
NAME123
NAME321
All my tries ended syntax mistake.

Comment: `I want to run: ping google123.com ping google321.com but not NAME123 NAME321` What do you mean by that?

Comment: this script is run by python: os.system(shell_cmd), where I can't use aliases, so I must grep aliases and run "inside" alias command

Answer (score 1):

**write_aliases_script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "#!/bin/bash\n\n" 1>script.sh;

alias | grep NAME |
grep -o "'\(.\+\)'" |
sed "s/'//g" 1>>script.sh;

chmod +x script.sh;
# uncomment after testing
#./script.sh;
```

**output**

```
$ ./write_aliases_script.sh 
$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

ping google123.com
ping google321.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Using eval you can make it run but be careful to not to invoke risky aliases:

```
eval $(alias | awk -F "'" '/NAME/{print $2}')
```